# Can't Reinstall Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I installed `devise 1.1.rc0` and haven't been able to get it to work in my existing application.

I changed the gem file to `gem 'devise'` without specifying the version. Ran bundle install. Then ran `rail destroy devise_install` since that's the command I used to install it.

*Then when I tried to reintall with `rails generate devise:install` it gives me this error:

> gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:50:in `method_missing': undefined method`devise' for # (NoMethodError)*

---

Ryan Bigg helped me figure out the above error was caused by the user model making a reference to devise, which after the uninstall causes an error. So I removed that reference.

Now I have this error.

gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize': uninitialized constant User (NameError)

What is this referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because Devise isn't configured, yet your model references it. Remove the call to the `devise` method (or comment it out) in any model that references it.

Comment: Thanks! I've removed the refernce to devise from within the user model. Now I have a new error. 

gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize': uninitialized constant User (NameError)

What is this referring to?

Comment: Will need to see more of the stacktrace for that error. Please open a new question for this problem.

Comment: I found that removing `devise_for :users` in config/routes.rb and rerunning the command fixed this for me. This was from a previous attempt at devise that was lying around.

Answer (score 1):

I found the same issue when upgrading from 1.8.7 and Rails 3.0.7 to 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.8.  The solution involves removing: 
    gem 'active_reload'